# Angular 4 Selected not working properly when it is given in model?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I'm trying to give a drop-down menu. By default, I need to select a value that needs to be displayed. When I'm not using a ngModel I'm able to display the default value.

**Without ngModel**

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let type of ListType" [value]="type .id">{{type .name}}</option>
</select>
```

The Above code works fine when we compile it. I'm able to see first value on the list to be displayed.

[image]

---

**With ngModel**

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedListType">
    <option *ngFor="let type of ListType" [value]="type .id">{{type .name}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

This is the display is empty.

Methods tried:

1. used Selected

`<option *ngFor="let type of ListType" [selected]="type.name === 'Dislike'" [value]="type .id">{{type .name}}</option>`

2. used attr.Selected

`<option *ngFor="let type  of ListType" [ngValue]="type " [attr.selected]="type .name== type.name ? true : null">{{ type.name  }}</option>`

EDIT

3. Even Tried to set the selected value via model still no outcome.

Is there any alternative way? 
Or
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Set some initial value to selectedListType

Comment: So your last edit says you tried to set selected value via model. So what value did you try and set?

Comment: selectedListType = "Dislike"; is the value that I set. and still facing an issue.@AJT_82

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are defining the value for the `select` as the `id` value, whereas you are feeding the `selectedListType` with the `name` property. So what you want to do is either provide the `id` value for `selectedListType`, so for example if your `ListType` looks like this:

```
[{id:1, name: 'Dislike'},{...}]
```

you want to set `selectedListyType` value as `1`. Other option is, if you do not know the id value you can do:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedListType = this.ListType.find(x => x.name === 'Dislike').id
}
```

and your template will then look like this:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedListType">
  <option *ngFor="let type of ListType" [value]="type.id">{{type.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was missing it  :")

Answer (score 2):

Try Keeping you value and ngModel same like

`value = {{type .id}}` and `[(ngModel)]= "selectedListType.id"`

and print the value once it is selected in html

```
<br>id is {{selectedListType.id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using reactive forms and ended up doing something like this to set the default value within my logic:

```
const defaultTopic = this.myoutline[0].name ? this.myoutline[0].name : '';
this.outline.controls['topic'].setValue(defaultTopic, {onlySelf: true});
```