# How to dynamically set selected attribute in Angular 4 using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular

I would like to preselect a particular option from dropdown after data is loaded on ngOnInit. However no option is getting selected.

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="segmentOneObject" (change)="segmentforOverlapOneSelected(segmentOneObject)" formControlName="segmentforOverlapOne" class="form-control overlap-segment-1" [disabled]="segmentations.length < 1">
 <option [disabled]="true" [ngValue]="'Select'">Select</option>
 <option *ngFor="let segment of segmentsForAnalysis" [ngValue]="segment" [selected]="segment.name == segmentsWithOverlapAnalysis[0].columns[0].name ? true : null">{{segment.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
submissionDetails: any;
ngOnInit() {
 let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'] as number;
 let job = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['job'] as number;
 this.devRequestService.getSubmission(id, job).subscribe((data) => {
   this.submissionDetails = data;
   this.segmentsForAnalysis = this.submissionDetails.segmentations.filter((segment) => {
     return segment.columns.length === 1;
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003432/angular-4-selected-not-working-when-it-is-given-in-model this should help you out, and you can go through this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14399.

Comment: You're using both ngModel and formControlName (so, templae-driven form and reactive form) on your select. Start by choosing one way over the other.