# Angular not showing "selected hidden" select option

Tags: angular, angular5

Here are my models:

```
dataModel: {
  company_size: any[],
  company_type: any[],
  employment_status: any[],
  english_knowledge: any[],
  experience_years: any[],
}

selectedDataModel: {
  company_size: any,
  company_type: any,
  employment_status: any,
  english_knowledge: any,
  experience_years: any,
}
```

Here's my template :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dm of dataModel | keys">
  <select *ngIf="dataModel[dm.key].values" [(ngModel)]="selectedDataModel[dm.key]" data-live-search="true">
    <option selected hidden>Choose Item</option>
    <option *ngFor="let obj of dataModel[dm.key].values" [id]="obj.id">
      {{obj.value}}
    </option>
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

Problem: When I add `ngModel` to select `<option selected hidden>Choose Item</option>` disappears (show empty field instead of "Choose Item")

---

I even tried this:

```
this.selectedDataModel = {
  company_size: -1,
  company_type: -1,
  employment_status: -1,
  english_knowledge: -1,
  experience_years: -1,
  highest_management_level: -1,
  industry: -1,
  industry_activity: -1,
  is_manager: -1,
  is_position_changed: -1,
  job_title: -1,
  job_function: -1,
  work_province: -1,
}
```

and

```
<option id="-1" selected hidden>Choose Item</option>
```

But it is not working yet.

Is there any solution?

Comment: there is some issue with the select tag while using in ngModel the best workaround is that you can assign the default value in ngModel you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003432/angular-4-selected-not-working-when-it-is-given-in-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is useing `[id]`. Instead of `[id]="obj.id"`, Use this one: `[value]="obj.id"`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement a "Choose an item" option in your select list is to define the first option hidden (or disabled) with the value `undefined`, and to remove it with `*ngIf` once a selection is made (see [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-iykba9)). Removing the option is useful in browsers where the hidden attribute does not actually hide the option (e.g. IE11).

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedDataModel[dm.key]" ...>
  <option [value]="undefined" *ngIf="!selectedDataModel[dm.key]" hidden>Choose an item</option>
  <option *ngFor="let obj of dataModel[dm.key].values" [value]="obj.id">{{obj.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example, take account that option="" or option=0, but not null or undefined

```
option=""

<select [(ngModel)]="option" >
    <option value="" hidden>Select one</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
</select>
```

Or

```
option:number=0 

<select [(ngModel)]="option" >
    <option value="0" hidden>Select one</option>
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
</select>
```